# Get last or first index of subproposition (stringrepresentation) starting with '(' or ending with ')'

Tags: python, string, brackets

I have some program, which produces strings of that kind:

```
s1 = '((q∧p)∧((q∨p)→s))'
```

or

```
s2 = (¬((r→s)∨q))
```

Furthermore I have the index position i1 of some '('-bracket or ')'-bracket.

I'm searching the index i2 position of the corresponding ')' or '('-bracket such that in the inner string between i1 and i2 (or i2 and i1) the count of '('-brackets is the same as the count of ')'-brackets.

Is their a simple function which represents that corresponding index?

Comment: use a stack to push and pop pairs as needed while tracking the index in a for loop. The builtin python `list` type can be used as a stack easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `stack` and put pairs `(index,char)`.

When you will try to put `)` then you should start remove pairs until you get `(` - this will be `(` corresponding to this `)`. Because you have pairs `index,char` so you can check if one of them has expected index `i1` or `i2` and then you may get index from other pairs to have expected result

```
s1 = '((q∧p)∧((q∨p)→s))'

i1 = 1  # 5


stack = []

for index, char in enumerate(s1):
    if char == ')':
        while True:
            index2, char2 = stack.pop(-1)
            if char2 == '(':
                if index2 == i1 or index == i1:
                    print(index2, index, s1[index2:index+1])
                break
    else:
        stack.append( (index,char) )
```

Result:

```
1 5 (q∧p)
```

---

If you put code in function then you can run it for different values.

```
def match(text, i1):

    stack = []
    
    for index, char in enumerate(text):
        if char == ')':
            while True:
                index2, char2 = stack.pop(-1)
                if char2 == '(':
                    if index2 == i1 or index == i1:
                        print(f'i1: {i1:2} => {text[i1]} | result: {index2:2}, {index:2} => {text[index2:index+1]}')
                    break
        else:
            stack.append( (index,char) )

# ----

s1 = '((q∧p)∧((q∨p)→s))'

print('---', s1, '---')
for i1 in [0, 1, 5, 7, 8, 12, 15, 16]:
    match(s1, i1)

s2 = '(¬((r→s)∨q))'

print('---', s2, '---')
for i1 in [0, 2, 3, 7, 10, 11]:
    match(s2, i1)
```

Result:

```
--- ((q∧p)∧((q∨p)→s)) ---
i1:  0 => ( | result:  0, 16 => ((q∧p)∧((q∨p)→s))
i1:  1 => ( | result:  1,  5 => (q∧p)
i1:  5 => ) | result:  1,  5 => (q∧p)
i1:  7 => ( | result:  7, 15 => ((q∨p)→s)
i1:  8 => ( | result:  8, 12 => (q∨p)
i1: 12 => ) | result:  8, 12 => (q∨p)
i1: 15 => ) | result:  7, 15 => ((q∨p)→s)
i1: 16 => ) | result:  0, 16 => ((q∧p)∧((q∨p)→s))
--- (¬((r→s)∨q)) ---
i1:  0 => ( | result:  0, 11 => (¬((r→s)∨q))
i1:  2 => ( | result:  2, 10 => ((r→s)∨q)
i1:  3 => ( | result:  3,  7 => (r→s)
i1:  7 => ) | result:  3,  7 => (r→s)
i1: 10 => ) | result:  2, 10 => ((r→s)∨q)
i1: 11 => ) | result:  0, 11 => (¬((r→s)∨q))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Simpler code - it puts only index for `(` from `text` (and skip other chars) and when it gets `)` from `text` then it gets last `index` from `stack` to have indexes for corresponding chars `(` and `)`

```
def match(text, idx):

    stack = []
    
    for index1, char in enumerate(text):
        if char == '(':
            # put every `(` on stack (or rather its index)
            stack.append( index1 )
        elif char == ')':
            # get `(` for current `)
            index2 = stack.pop(-1)
            if index1 == idx or index2 == idx:
                return index1, index2

# --- main ---

text = '((q∧p)∧((q∨p)→s))'

print('---', text, '---')

for idx in [0, 1, 5, 7, 8, 12, 15, 16]:
    result = match(text, idx)

    if result: # to detect `None`
        index1, index2 = result
        print(f'idx: {idx:2} => {text[idx]} | result: {index2:2}, {index1:2} => {text[index2:index1+1]}')
    else:
        print("can't find for idx:", idx)

# ---

text = '(¬((r→s)∨q))'

print('---', text, '---')

for idx in [0, 2, 3, 7, 10, 11]:
    result = match(text, idx)

    if result: # to detect `None`
        index1, index2 = result
        print(f'idx: {idx:2} => {text[idx]} | result: {index2:2}, {index1:2} => {text[index2:index1+1]}')
    else:
        print("can't find for idx:", idx)
```

---

Using `range(len(text))` it can find all matching pairs `( )`

```
text = '(¬((r→s)∨q)) ((q∧p)∧((q∨p)→s))'

print('---', text, '---')

for idx in range(len(text)):
    if text[idx] == '(':  # skip duplicated results for `)`
        result = match(text, idx)
        
        if result: # to detect `None`
            index1, index2 = result
            print(f'idx: {idx:2} => {text[idx]} | result: {index2:2}, {index1:2} => {text[index2:index1+1]}')
        #else:
        #    print("can't find for idx:", idx)
```

The same for `enumerate(text)`

```
print('---', text, '---')

for idx,char in enumerate(text):
    if char == '(':  # skip duplicated results for `)`
        result = match(text, idx)
        
        if result: # to detect `None`
            index1, index2 = result
            print(f'idx: {idx:2} => {text[idx]} | result: {index2:2}, {index1:2} => {text[index2:index1+1]}')
        #else:
        #    print("can't find for idx:", idx)
```

Result:

```
--- (¬((r→s)∨q)) ((q∧p)∧((q∨p)→s)) ---
idx:  0 => ( | result:  0, 11 => (¬((r→s)∨q))
idx:  2 => ( | result:  2, 10 => ((r→s)∨q)
idx:  3 => ( | result:  3,  7 => (r→s)
idx: 13 => ( | result: 13, 29 => ((q∧p)∧((q∨p)→s))
idx: 14 => ( | result: 14, 18 => (q∧p)
idx: 20 => ( | result: 20, 28 => ((q∨p)→s)
idx: 21 => ( | result: 21, 25 => (q∨p)
```